# A 19th Century Probability Problems Book Written by a British Monk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, math-history

I'm trying to find this book I occasionally used for didactic and fun-inducing purposes when I taught basic probability but I can't remember the author or the title, here are the facts I vaguely recall about it:

- It was freely available via Google Books as it's from I believe around 19th century
- Most modern probability and basic combinatorics word problems are based on all those problems in the book, some people don't even realize that
- The author wrote it during his tenure at a monastery somewhere in modern-day UK
- It has a bunch of problems with rather exotic/not so popular these days games like bridge
- It has a problem about men and women dancing in like rows (imagine those country dances of regional British nobility you see in some Jane Austen film adaptations and the whole idea behind such musical endeavors is matchmaking) and the question of the problem had a funny wording like "in how many way can a marriage be effectuated between the dancers at the ball?"

Any pointers to what the book is or a link to Google Books would be much, much appreciated!

Comment: Are you thinking of [Charles Lutwidge Dodgson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Carroll) who published many books including some on mathematical and probability problems?  He was not really a monk, though he was ordained a deacon, never married, and spent most of his life at Christ Church, a cathedral and a college in Oxford

Comment: Or maybe [William Allan Whitworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Allen_Whitworth), author of [_Choice and Chance_](https://archive.org/details/choicechancewith00whituoft/page/n4/mode/2up) ?  He was a priest.  His book is chock-a-block full of probability and combinatorics problems.

Comment: @Henry haha, no it's not Lewis Carol, lol.

Comment: @kimchilover YES! The name sounds so familiar let me check out the problems in that Choice and Chance book, thank you!

Comment: @Henry plus, Lewis Caroll was too conservative for such inventing such frivolous combinatorics problems in context of mischievous dancing where a potential, (God-forbid!!), a "marriage can be effectuated"

Comment: @kimchilover yes, this is the book and found the question about the dance, there are a lot of them actually. Really happy to find this masterpiece! Thank you! A side note: I'm a kimchi addict myself, I wish there was a Stackoverflow dedicated to comfort pickled foods, I'd be one of the top contributors, lol.